# $_POST function won't work?

Tags: php, post, text, field, move

I'm having some trouble getting the text field from the page found here:[Here](http://legacyserver.info/VotingScriptfbxiz.php)
And moving it here: [Here](http://legacyserver.info/Untitled-3.php)
I have tried the $_post function as I have seen before, but it doesn't seem to carry the info over!

Here is the script currently for the first page described:

```
<?php
// Creator: Will Renfroe
// All rights Reserved

//Vote Sites and MySQL
$DBNAME="mysql";
$DBUSER="mysql";
$DBPASSWORD="mysql";
$DBHOST="mysql";

///////////////////
// SCRIPT
///////////////////
mysql_connect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD) or die("<center>Cannot connect to MySQL</center>");
mysql_select_db($DBNAME) or die("<center>Cannot select DB</center>");
/////////

?>

<?php
    include("secure.php");
    if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
    $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
} else {
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}

if(isset($_POST['dovote'])){
check_inject();

    //Get user id from session
    $userid=secure($_POST["nick"]);
    $time=time();

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT nick,time FROM votesdb WHERE ip='$ipaddress'");
    $checkip=mysql_num_rows($query);
    $iprow=mysql_fetch_row($query);

    $query=mysql_query("SELECT time FROM votesdb WHERE nick='$userid'");
    $checkuser=mysql_num_rows($query);
    $userrow=mysql_fetch_row($query);

    if ($checkuser){
        //if user vote
        if ($checkip and $time>$iprow[1]){$canvote=1;}
        if (!$checkip and $time>$userrow[0]){$canvote=1;}
    }else{
        //if user never vote
        if ($checkip and $time>$iprow[1]){$canvote=1;}
        if (!$checkip){$canvote=1;}
    }

    //Do Vote
    if ($canvote){
        $newtime=time()+60*60*24;

        if ($checkuser){
            //update
            mysql_query("UPDATE votesdb SET time=$newtime, ip='$ipaddress', votes=votes+1, flags=flags+1 WHERE nick='$userid'");
        }else{
            //insert
            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO votesdb(nick,time,ip,votes,flags) VALUES ('$userid',$newtime,'$ipaddress',1,1)");
        }

        //Add nick to nicklist table
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO nicklist(nick) VALUES ('$userid')");

        echo "<font color='red'>You can vote every 24 hours to get reward.</font>";
    }else{
        echo "<font color='green'>thank you for voting!</font>";
    }
}

?>






<style type="text/css">
.minecrafttext {
    font-family: "Volter (Goldfish)";
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #0F3;
}
.minecrafttext {
    font-family: "Volter (Goldfish)";
}
</style>
<body background="http://files.enjin.com/121395/19.gif" bgproperties="fixed"><div style="text-align: center;"> <img style="border: medium none;" alt="" title="" src="http://files.enjin.com/121395/Vote_For_Diamonds.png"><span style="color: rgb(255, 165, 0);"><br>You will get <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18pt; color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">10</span></span> <img style="border: medium none; width: 37px; height: 34px;" alt="" title="" src="http://www.minecraftwiki.net/images/9/90/Diamond_%28Gem%29.png"><span style="color: rgb(255, 165, 0);">for voting on the sites below!</span><br></div><div style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(30, 144, 255); font-weight: bold;"></span><span style="color: rgb(30, 144, 255); font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Directions:</span><br>
  <br>
  <span class="minecrafttext">Vote right here: </span>
</div>

<center>
  <form target="_blank" action="http://www.minecraftservers.net/vote.php?id=1991" method="post"> 
  <p>
    <input onClick="document.getElementById('vote4').disabled=false" value="Minecraftservers.net" name="vote1" id="vote1" type="submit" />
  </p>
  <p class="minecrafttext">And here:&nbsp;</p>
</form>
<form target="_blank" action="http://www.minestatus.net/15901-freebuildxiz" method="post">
  <input onClick="document.getElementById('vote5').disabled=false" disabled="disabled" value="Minestatus" name="vote1" id="vote4" type="submit" />&nbsp;</form>
<br/>
  <form method="POST">
    <font color='lime' class="minecrafttext"><strong>Put your In-Game-Name here!</strong></font><br/>
    <input name="nick"/><br/>
<form method="POST">
<input name="dovote" type="submit" value="Receive Diamond" onClick="document.getElementById('vote5').disabled=false" id="vote5" disabled="disabled" onSubmit="return nameempty();" /> 
</form> 
<a href="http://legacyserver.info/fbxtop.php" target="http://legacyserver.info/fbxtop.php" class="minecrafttext">Click here to see the Top 10 voters!</a>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

And here for the second one:

```
<body background="http://files.enjin.com/121395/19.gif" bgproperties="fixed"><div style="text-align: center;"><br /> <img style="border: medium none;" alt="" title="" src="http://files.enjin.com/121395/Vote_For_Diamonds.png"><br /><center><font color='cyan'>Click below to start the vote for diamonds process!</font></center><br /><br />
<form method="POST" action="VotingScriptfbxiz.php">
<input type="image" method="POST" action="VotingScriptfbxiz.php" src="http://files.enjin.com/121395/JulieGloopUI(43)45(REV2).png" alt="Submit value="POST" input name="VoteVerify" id="submitButton" />
```

It does not want to function properly when I try to move the text feild from the first page to the second one and still have it submit the information correctly.

Also, there seems to be some sort of problem with the 1st script described, where it says that you voted every single time, but it doesn't want to even add you to the database, I have tried many versions of this and it suddenly while i was messing

Comment: Your image input doesn't need methods or actions on it, also, you don't close your alt property properly. Also, you have like 9 forms, some of which are unclosed, some of which have no actions.

Comment: @will, on a side note, it may help you to think of $_POST as a (super global) variable rather than a function.

Comment: There are lots of very odd errors in that markup. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Obviously, I'm still learning, and I do not have the cleanest work, I'm actually looking for someone to teach me rather than looking at youtube tutorials :/

Comment: You have tried to run your code within this condtion `if(isset($_POST['dovote']))`. But the submit button "dovote" is `disabled='disabled'`.

Comment: @Kristian What exactly do you mean by that? As I have stated many times, I'm very new at this and unexperienced

Comment: Trying reading when you're done youtubing: http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second script is wrong. You need to change that to:

```
<body background="http://files.enjin.com/121395/19.gif" bgproperties="fixed">
   <div style="text-align: center;"><br /> 
       <img style="border: medium none;" alt="" title="" src="http://files.enjin.com/121395/Vote_For_Diamonds.png"/><br />
<center><font color='cyan'>Click below to start the vote for diamonds process!</font></center><br /><br />
<form method="POST" action="VotingScriptfbxiz.php">
  <input type="image" src="http://files.enjin.com/121395/JulieGloopUI(43)45(REV2).png" alt="Submit" value="POST" /> 
  <input name="VoteVerify" id="submitButton" />
  </form>
 </div>
 <body/>
```

Why are you using action and method for image tag. No need of that. Also you din't close the form tag and input type="image" tag

Also use a validator to validate.

Why are you unnecessarily using 
 tags. use styles to make it correct.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! I have not tried this yet, but when I do , Ill give you the top answer ;)

Comment: Wait, it worked for what my 1st question was... but the entire thing still just... doesn't work you can see what I mean here:  [link](http://freebuildxiz.com/)

Comment: The problem is even if you vote with a user that is not adding vote to the database right ?? is that the issue

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by that, but it does not verify the user correctly, its something with the if statements, it says "you can only vote once every 24 hours." Even if you have not voted in the last 24 hours, and if you look here: http://legacyserver.info/fbxtop.php you will see that nothing in the database changes when you vote. It does not add you, and you get the you get the message you get if your vote fails because you already voted.

Comment: I am getting confused. One thing send me the url of your site and is the first script added here is the php thing ??

Comment: And yes, the first script here is a non-working php script. I have no idea what happened... it was working, and then I think I messed something up while tweaking it.

Comment: http://legacyserver.info/VotingScriptfbxiz.php . Where is the option to vote. I think its working .

Comment: But! haveing the text field on the previous page still doesn't work! It keeps sending the form with no username, the whole process it supposed to start here: http://legacyserver.info/Untitled-3.php

Comment: It sends the form, but with no "nick" so it shows up in the mysql database blank... am I explaining this well or no? I'm very new to coding in general..